css color transparant color: #00000030; works?
I found this 'trick' a while ago. Adding two digits to a hex color sets the transparency.
This works in Google Chrome (2024-04) and the Edge browser.
color: #000000; (= black)
color: #00000030; (=black transparent to 30%)
30 is an example you can change it to a desired level of transparency.
Does anyone know if this will be a standard? (I hope so!) I can't find any information on this.

You are talking about RGBA  (where A stands for alpha channel) and of course it's already a standard.

it already is a standard for more than 10 years. Hex can either be  12-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit or 32-bit. 16-bit and 32-bit hex colors have the 4 channels for the alpha value (transparency).

@DiegoD this is not RGBA - hex always allowed an alpha channel as well.

@tacoshy I don't know what to say...hex per se is a numeric system.. RGB stands for RGB and if there's another encoding supporting the alpha channel how should be called if not RGBA?

the color code is a hex color not a RGB color. 2 different standard beside the usage of decimal vs hex numbers. the main difference is that hex can also be 12-bit and 16-bit while RGB itself is always either 24-bit or 32-bit.

 got it.. yes you are right

@MisterJojo 48/256 = 18,75%

it is not 30%.--> 30 hex = 48 dec(base 10 -> 3×16 + 0). So it is 18.82% ((48*100/255))

@tacoshy the max is 255 and not 256, xFF == 255 ==> 100% (0 <--> 100 => 101 values)

Short answer
Hex always supports an additional 4th channel for the alpha (transparency).
As a 16-bit color (#RGBA) or 32-bit color (#RRRGGBBAA) the last or last 2 digits stand for the alpha channel.
However, note that the alpha channel unlike Adobe RGBA, does not use numeric numbers but also Hex numbers.

30 (hexadecimal) = (3x16) + (0x1)
30 (hexadecimal) = 48 + 0
30 (hexadecimal) = 48

as the alpha channel with 2 digits is 8-bit (2^8 = 256) you have 48/256 transparency (18.75%).
The other way around to really get 30% you can use this calculation:

x = 256 * 30%
x = 256 * 0.3
X = 76.8
x = 77

hexadecimal = 77 (decimal)
hexadecimal = 77 / 16
hexadecimal = 4 remainder 13 (D)
hexadecimal = 4D

Extended Answer Addressing Comments
Hex has to be split from normal (Adobe) RGB or RGBA. The main difference is that (Adobe) RGB/RGBA uses decimal numbers and always 8-bit color channels. The alpha value there is given as a decimal float number ranging from 0 to 1 or as a float percentage number.
Hex is also an RGB/RGBA but with either 4-bit or 8-bit color channels where the alpha value is as well either the 4-bit or 8-bit color:
| Type         | Format    | Range                           | Bit |
| ------------ | --------- | ------------------------------- | --- |
| 3-digit Hex  | #RGB      | 0-F, 0-F, 0-F                   | 12  |
| 4-digit Hex  | #RGBA     | 0-F, 0-F, 0-F, 0-F              | 16  |
| 6-digit Hex  | #RRGGBB   | 00-FF, 00-FF, 00-FF             | 24  |
| 8-digit Hex  | #RRGGBBAA | 00-FF, 00-FF, 00-FF, 00-FF      | 32  |
| (Adobe) RGB  | RGB       | 0-255, 0-255, 0-255             | 24  |
| (Adobe) RGBA | RGBA      | 0.255, 0-255, 0-255, 0-1/0-100% | 32  |   


You can use that notation but its values are in the Hex color space that goes from 00 to ff (ff is 255 in decimal encoding), so the number 30 doesn't mean 30%.
You can see an example on the MDN color page that the 50% transparent red is:
color: #ff000080;

There is a nice table on this page with the Hex values listed:
How Hex Colors Work
Also read here: Hex colors: Numeric representation for "transparent"?
